# Javascript - Filter 2D Array by List

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Seems like this should be very simple; I have a 2D array:

```
[["Apple",123],
 ["Berry",234],
 ["Cherry",345],
 ["Dog",456]]
```

I have a list:

```
["Apple","Dog"]
```

I would like to return an array based on the list items:

```
[["Apple",123],
 ["Dog",456]]
```

Note: the real 2D array has 100 rows and 10 columns.  Thanks !

Bonus, a command that will filter to just "Apple" and "Dog" rows as well as "Product" and "Quality" columns:

```
[["Product","Quantity","Quality"],
 ["Apple",123,"Red"],
 ["Berry",234,"Blue"],
 ["Cherry",345,"Choke"],
 ["Dog",456,"Big"]]
```

Expected result:

```
[["Product","Quality"],
 ["Apple","Red"],
 ["Dog","Big"]]
```

or

```
[["Apple","Red"],
 ["Dog","Big"]]
```

Again, the order and number of columns and rows is variable.

Update:

Based on the two answers below, neither filtering approach seems to work for my use-case.  As such, I will provide the following context.  Rather than "Products" like "Apple" and "Dog", my array is more like:

```
[["URL","Quantity","Quality"],
 ["http://abcd.defg.eghi.com/alphabet/abcd1234-ef12-23ed-eafe/q?key=123-abc",123,"Red"],
 ["http://abcd.defg.eghi.com/alphabet/aecd934-ef12-23ed-jufe/q?key=176-abc",234,"Blue"],
 ["http://abcd.defg.eghi.com/alphabet/eafcd134-ef24-23ed-eefe/q?key=145-abc",345,"Choke"],
 ["http://abcd.deeg.eghi.com/alphabet/abcd1234-ef12-23ed-45fe/q?key=187-abc",456,"Big"]]
```

and my list is like:

```
["http://abcd.defg.eghi.com/alphabet/abcd1234-ef12-23ed-eafe/q?key=123-abc","http://abcd.deeg.eghi.com/alphabet/abcd1234-ef12-23ed-45fe/q?key=187-abc"]
```

My expectation is that the first and fourth row would be returned, as with Apple and Dog, but for some reason the URLs aren't filtering.  Are there any special characters that may be affecting this function ?

Comment: array.filter(([key,value]) => keys.includes(key))

Comment: @antokhio Thanks, but I really don't know how to use this for a list.

Comment: `keys` is `list`, array is your 2D array

Comment: I think it's time for you to spend a little more time thinking about your problem and try to come up with a solution on your own.  It seems to me you're giving up a little too easy.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @Cooper, but three hours to filter some arrays seems to me like I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on yout second use case. You can use various of Array functions to achieve it. Here's an example:

```js
const data = [
  ["URL", "Quantity", "Quality"],
  ["http://abcd.defg.eghi.com/alphabet/abcd1234-ef12-23ed-eafe/q?key=123-abc", 123, "Red"],
  ["http://abcd.defg.eghi.com/alphabet/aecd934-ef12-23ed-jufe/q?key=176-abc", 234, "Blue"],
  ["http://abcd.defg.eghi.com/alphabet/eafcd134-ef24-23ed-eefe/q?key=145-abc", 345, "Choke"],
  ["http://abcd.deeg.eghi.com/alphabet/abcd1234-ef12-23ed-45fe/q?key=187-abc", 456, "Big"]
];

function filterData(data, columns, targets) {
  const [headers, ...rows] = data;
  const filterIndex = headers.indexOf(columns[0]);
  const indices = columns.map(column => headers.indexOf(column));
  return [columns,
    ...rows.filter(row => targets.includes(row[filterIndex]))
    .map(row => row.filter((item, i) => indices.includes(i)))
  ];
}

// columns you want to keep
const columns = ["URL", "Quality"];

// targets you want to filter
const urls = [
  "http://abcd.defg.eghi.com/alphabet/abcd1234-ef12-23ed-eafe/q?key=123-abc",
  "http://abcd.deeg.eghi.com/alphabet/abcd1234-ef12-23ed-45fe/q?key=187-abc"
];

const filtered = filterData(data, columns, urls);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, but for some reason it is not working for my use case.  Can you check my updated question and see if that helps ?

Comment: You probably forgot to change `Product` to `URL` to match your actual dataset. I've updated the answer according to your updated question.

Comment: Hmm, no; the columns are labeled correctly.  It must be something else...

Comment: When I run this code, what I get returned is just the headers: [["URL","Quality"]].

Comment: Make sure your `urls` array for filtering matches the first item of some rows.

Comment: I see; I moved my columns around.  Your code snippet assumes that the column I am using to filter is the first one.  It's actually variable, but always based on the header.  I probably should have explained this more thoroughly, but I didn't expect to be bogged down by what seems like it should have been simple.

Comment: I've updated my answer, now it uses the first column you provide in `columns` array. Which doesn't have to be the first column in the row dataset.

Comment: Brilliant; thank you for sticking with me.

Answer (score 3):

```
function tooeasy() {
  let arr2 = ["Apple","Dog"];
  let arr1 = [["Apple",123],["Berry",234],["Cherry",345], ["Dog",456]].filter(r => ~arr2.indexOf(r[0]));
  Logger.log(arr1);
}

Execution log
7:46:28 PM  Notice  Execution started
7:46:28 PM  Info    [[Apple, 123.0], [Dog, 456.0]]
7:46:30 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

- [Array.methods()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [bitwise not ~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

> Only one question at at time

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to be working for my array, which includes a key like: "http://abcd.defg.eghi.com/alphabet/abcd1234-ef12-23ed-eafe/q?key=123-abc"  Is there any character that needs escaped here ?

Comment: I do not  see an array.

Comment: I do not follow links to unfamiliar urls.  If you wish it to be part of the question then post it in the question.

Comment: The link is made up, but represents more closely the key on which I am trying to filter.

Comment: If you wish to add more to the question then post it into the question in a more understandable format.

Comment: Done.  Thank you.

Comment: +1 for the interesting bitwise usage. i never utilized bitwise as it's not somethings that come to my mind when i try to solve things. looking at your answer, can the same result be achieved by doing `arr2.indexOf(r[0]) + 1`?

Comment: Maybe `arr2.includes(r[0])` is more intuitive?